# Acessing Variable Declared inside match outside in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i am using try and catch method to catch exception while reading a file in Dataframe using below code

```
import scala.io.StdIn
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val filename = "s3a://bucketname/moving/file.csv"

def CustomSchemaDataFrame(fileName: String):Try[DataFrame] = {

try {
     val df_custom_schema = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(filename) 
      Success(df_custom_schema)
    } catch {
      case unknown: Exception => {
        println(s"Unknown exception: $unknown")
        Failure(unknown)
      }
    }
  }

CustomSchemaDataFrame(filename) match {
  case Success(df_custom_schema) => {
      println("File Read Successfully")
      df_custom_schema.printSchema()
      df_custom_schema.show(true)
  }
  case Failure(ex) => {
      println("error code", ex)
  }
}
```

what i would like to perform next is to export df_custom_schema out side match further to perform operation out side match loop.

some thing like this below

```
CustomSchemaDataFrame(filename) match {
  case Success(df_custom_schema) => {
      println("File Read Successfully")
      df_custom_schema.printSchema()
      df_custom_schema.show(true)
     val custom_schema = df_custom_schema
  }
  case Failure(ex) => {
      println("error code", ex)
  }
}

custom_schema.printSchema()
```

when i am using above custom_schema.printSchema() inside match its working fine but when i am trying to access it outside its throwing error. Is there a way to access the values out side match case. as i want to perform several other operations on this data frame.

regards
mahi

Comment: Which error is thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why can't you just write:

```
val custom_schema= CustomSchemaDataFrame(filename)

custom_schema match {
  case Success(df_custom_schema) => {
      println("File Read Successfully")
      df_custom_schema.printSchema()
      df_custom_schema.show(true)
     val custom_schema = df_custom_schema
  }
  case Failure(ex) => {
      println("error code", ex)
  }
}

custom_schema.get.printSchema()
```

of course you may have to check if custom_schema is success

```
if ( custom_schema.isSuccess )
  custom_schema.get.printSchema
```

Comment: Thanks for input gtosto, i need to also get the entire data of the schema to perform some operations on them. how to obtain that above is yielding schema only

Comment: with `custom_schema.get` you get the dataframe returned by the function `CustomSchemaDataFrame`

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't access values inside the case of the pattern matching. It's a local to the scope of that function.

What you would need to do is return the result from the pattern matching and continue to process that result.

This doesn't make much sense however since you have to return something valid from both the `Success` and `Failure` blocks and then you're probably better of using `recoverWith`.

So typically you would either do something like

```scala
Try {
  spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(filename)
} match {
  case Success(df) =>
    // ...
    // do all success related stuff to df here
    // ...
  case Failure(t) =>
    println(t)
}
```

or, if there's some kind of default you want in case of failure

```scala
Try {
  spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(filename)
}.recoverWith {
  case t =>
    println(t)
    Success(DefaultDF())
}.map { df =>
  // do stuff here
}
```